# KitScenarist symbol lookup error

Tags: error-handling

I used to use KitScenarist to arrange my story scenes but recently it doesn't open up, echoing this error when using terminal to run it:

`/usr/share/KIT/Scenarist/Scenarist: symbol lookup error: /usr/share/KIT/Scenarist/Scenarist: undefined symbol: _ZN18QWidgetTextControl12processEventEP6QEventRK7QMatrixP7QWidget, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had installed KitScenarist using the deb file available on their website which installed the app as "scenarist".
I removed it using `sudo apt remove scenarist` and installed kitscenarist from the repositories using this code:

```
sudo apt install kitscanrist
```

it works fine, and asks me to update using their website, but I obviously avoid that, and I will keep updating it using apt updates.